# Specifying class name instead of id in Ajax on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need to know, how to fetch class name from div instead of id when using Ajax on Rails

my coding is like below,

```
<div id="test_test1" class="test">
</div>

<div id="test_test2" class = "test">
</div>
```

and on Controller,

```
page.replace_html "test_test1", "<button>Thanks</button>"
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want replace values of **all** divs with class 'test' you can use from rjs this code

```
page.select('.test').each do |value|  
  value.update 'new value' 
end
```

If only **one** of them - then you shouldn't do it from rjs because of class of dom element not unique. You can use link_to_remote callbacks. See docs here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001645

Answer (score 1):

```
page << "$$('div.test').first.replace('<button>Thanks</button>')"
```